# Flood-Fill ending too soon, not coming back to starting position

Tags: java, flood-fill

I am working on a minesweeper like game and am stuck on revealing the squares that are empty. Currently I have 2 separate arrays, one that holds the game board that the player can see after each selection, and one holding the location of bombs and the tile numbers.

```
    playerView Array * * * * *    dataView Array *1000
                     * * * * *                   22000
                     * * * * *    the no spaces  *1011
                     * * * * *    is important   1101*
                     * * * * *                   00011
```

I did this because at the end of each game we need to show the full board or the dataView Array.

When doing the flood fill I first check for any out-of-bounds checks, then see if the selected tile has a "0" in it and see if we have already passed over the tile. This method was passed coordinates that already passed a bomb check so I don't have to worry about that. If the tile contains a "0" I set playerView array at the passed coordinates to "0 " then pass adjacent coordinates through flood fill. If the selected tile does not contain a "0" in dataView then I set playerView to the value in dataView and return.

I can't wrap my head around what I am missing. I have looked at similar problems here, even implemented the code line by line into mine, making tweaks as needed. I cannot get this to fill. Currently my code will fill down a column until it hits a number other than "0", it sets that number correctly, then asks me to select the next coordinate.

As I said above I have tried to implement some of the other solutions I have found on here and youtube but haven't had any luck. I started out with a nested for loop to loop me over each adjacent cell and run the flood fill function but it was too hard to track and I couldn't debug it at all. I broke it down into what I have below.

```
    public void clearTiles(int row, int col) {

    if (row < 1 || col < 1) {
        return;
    }
    if (row > 10 || col > 10) {
        return;
    }
    if ("0".equals(Grid.dataView[row - 1][col - 1]) && !"0 
        ".equals(Grid.playerView[row - 1][col - 1])) {
            Grid.playerView[row - 1][col - 1] = "0 ";
            check2 = Grid.playerView[row - 1][col - 1];


            clearTiles((row + 1), col);
            clearTiles((row - 1), col);
            clearTiles(row, (col + 1));            
            clearTiles(row, (col - 1));
    } else if (!"0 ".equals(Grid.playerView[row - 1][col - 1]) || !"0".equals(Grid.dataView[row - 1][col - 1])){
        Grid.playerView[row - 1][col - 1] = Grid.dataView[row - 1][col - 1];
        return;
    }

    sweepLoop();
}
```

Taking the example posted above. I would get this.

```
  passing row 1, column 3        passing row 1, column 4
playerView Array * * 0 * *         * * * 0 *
                 * * 0 * *         * * * 0 *
                 * * 0 * *         * * * 1 *
                 * * 0 * *         * * * * *
                 * * 0 * *         * * * * *
```

Expected Result:

```
  passing row 1, column 3
playerView Array * 1 0 0 0
                 * 2 0 0 0
                 * 1 0 1 1
                 1 1 0 1 *
                 0 0 0 1 1
```

Comment: Did you try debugging it? Stepping over all the instructions? Something tells me that the first condition is incorrect - `[row-1][col-1]` is the "current" position or is it something else? When you call the `clearTiles` later on it looks like `[row][col]` is the "current" position. Which one is it? What is more, the question most likely misses some code, no idea what is `sweepLoop()` and `clearTiles()`

Comment: @Amongalen Whoops, updated the code to include the entire method. So the row, col that is passed into the method is the users selection. User selects (1, 1) that is passed to the method. (1, 1) correlates with (0, 0) of gridArray and playerArray. That is why I `[row - 1][col - 1]` to find my current position in the Arrays. When I go to pass that back into the function I use [row - 1][col] to run clearTiles() on the tile above me. In the case of passing (1, 1) I would get (0, 1) passed which would be handled by my out of bounds exception.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full source code as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.